# ¿Cómo gestionar contador array = vacio?

Tags: php, array, count

Tengo un array multidimensional, que son *incidencias => tecnico => numero incidencias => id*, zona.

O sea que 1 técnico tiene n incidencias y la incidencia tiene n campos o datos.

El problema lo tengo en:

```
incidencias->usuario1 -> incidencia1 -> idIncidencia1
             usuario1 -> incidencia2 -> idIncidencia2
incidencias->usuario2 -> incidencia3 -> idIncidencia3
             usuario2 -> incidencia4 -> idIncidencia4
             usuario2 -> incidencia5 -> idIncidencia5
incidencias->usuario3 -> NO TIENE INCIDENCIA NI TAMPOCO CAMPOS
```

Si hago el `count(incidencias['usuario1']) = 1 (0,1)`

Si hago el `count(incidencias['usuario2']) = 2 (0,1,2)`

Pero si hago `count(incidencias['usuario3'])` me da el error, no sé cómo controlar el count vacio, o si es vacío.

He intentado con:

```
if(count(incidencias['usuario3']) == 0 || 
    count(incidencias['usuario3']) == null || 
    is_null(count(incidencias['usuario3']) )){
    echo "Vacío";
}
```

Pero como digo no sé cómo controlar el `count(incidencias['usuario3'])`.

> ```
> ( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: usuario3 in /informe.php on line 45
> Call Stack
> # Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0015  442560  {main}( )   .../informe.php:0
>
> ( ! ) Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that
> implements Countable in informe.php on line 45 Call Stack
> # Time    Memory  Function    Location 1  0.0015  442560  {main}( )   .../informe.php:0
> ```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Gracias.

Adjunto código:

```
<?php
$hoy = date('Y-m-d 00:00:01');
include_once('../../admin/dbconect.php');
$fecha = date(('Y-m-d H:i:s'), strtotime($hoy."- 3 days"));
//abrimos conexión bdatos
$database  = new Connection();
$db        = $database->open();

$sqlTecnicos = "SELECT DISTINCT NOMBRE_TECNICO from tecnicos where ELIMINADA = 0 ORDER BY NOMBRE_TECNICO";
$tecnicosdb = $db->query($sqlTecnicos)->fetchAll();
//var_dump($tecnicosdb);

$incidenciaArray = array();
$technicals = array();
foreach ($tecnicosdb as $tech) {
    # code...
    $technicals[] = $tech['NOMBRE_TECNICO'];
}
//var_dump($technicals);


for ($a = 0;$a < sizeof($technicals);$a++) {    
    # code...
    $nombreTecnico = $technicals[$a];
    
    //$emailTecnico = $tecnicosdb[$a]['EMAIL_TECNICO'];
    //echo $a." - ".sizeof($incidencias)."<br>";
    $sqlIncidencias = "SELECT * from registros where (ESTADO_AVERIA='ABIERTA' OR ESTADO_AVERIA = 'PTE MATERIAL' OR ESTADO_AVERIA = 'RECLAMADA' OR ESTADO_AVERIA = 'PTE INGRESO') AND EMAIL_ENVIADO_A = '$nombreTecnico' AND (FECHA_HORA < '$fecha') AND ELIMINADA = 0 ORDER BY ESTADO_AVERIA, ID ASC";
    $incidencias = $db->query($sqlIncidencias)->fetchAll();
    //var_dump($incidencias);
    //echo '<h1>Buenos días '.$nombreTecnico.", le recuerdo que tiene pendientes los siguientes avisos</h1>";
    for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($incidencias); $x++) {
        # code...
        $incidenciaArray[$nombreTecnico][$x]['ID'] = $incidencias[$x]['ID'];
        $incidenciaArray[$nombreTecnico][$x]['ZONA'] = $incidencias[$x]['ZONA'];
        $incidenciaArray[$nombreTecnico][$x]['ESTADO'] = $incidencias[$x]['ESTADO_AVERIA'];
        $incidenciaArray[$nombreTecnico][$x]['FECHA'] = DATE('d-m-Y',strtotime($incidencias[$x]['FECHA_HORA']));
        $incidenciaArray[$nombreTecnico][$x]['POBLACION'] = $incidencias[$x]['POBLACION'];
    }
}

for($i = 0;$i < count($technicals);$i++){
    echo $technicals[$i]."<br>";
    $tec = $technicals[$i];
    for($x = 0; $x < count($incidenciaArray[$technicals[$i]]); $x++){
        if(is_null(count($incidenciaArray[$technicals[$i]]))){
            echo "No tiene incidencias retrasadas";
        }else{
            echo $incidenciaArray[$tec][$x]['ID'];
            echo $incidenciaArray[$tec][$x]['ZONA'];
            echo $incidenciaArray[$tec][$x]['ESTADO'];
            echo $incidenciaArray[$tec][$x]['FECHA'];
            echo $incidenciaArray[$tec][$x]['POBLACION'];
            echo "<hr/>";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende. ¿Podrías explicar mejor qué es lo que te sucede? De paso, haz un `var_dump($incidencias);` y agrégalo a la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta. Gracias.

Comment: He modificado la consulta, no puedo hace un var_dump() porque saldrían datos muy sensibles...

Comment: Puedes poner datos ficticios,es para ver la estructura interna de los datos. Si la analizas sabrás cómo leerlos.

Comment: No si leerlos los leo bien, y se ven bien. El problema que tengo es cuando tengo un subarray sin registros e intento hacer un count() para que si da 0 o el valor que sea = 0, null, empty... no lose. Ese valor, me salte el registro.

Comment: Pues pon un extracto, con datos ficticios, de esa parte en la que tienes problemas.

Comment: Adjunto código
````
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución, simplemente tenía que comprobar lo siguiente:

```
if(!isset($incidenciaArray[$technicals[$i]]){
    echo "No existe registro";
}
```

Mil gracias a todos.